# How to make canvas drawing smooth and realistic

Tags: javascript, html

I am coloring a canvas using the following code. But the drawn line are not smooth. At edges it's more like box than a smooth edge. How can i make it smooth and realistic?

```
function touchStartHandler(e) {
        var touch = e.changedTouches[0];

        drawPath[touch.identifier] = touch;

        context.fillStyle = strokeColor;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(drawPath[touch.identifier].pageX - content.offsetLeft,
                drawPath[touch.identifier].pageY - content.offsetTop,
                strokeWidth / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
}

function touchMoveHandler(e) {
        var touches = e.changedTouches, touchesLength = touches.length, currentDrawPath = null, i = 0;

        context.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
        context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
        context.lineJoin = 'round';

        for (i = 0; i < touchesLength; i += 1) {
            currentDrawPath = drawPath[touches[i].identifier];
            if (currentDrawPath !== undefined) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(currentDrawPath.pageX - content.offsetLeft,
                        currentDrawPath.pageY - content.offsetTop);
                context.lineTo(touches[i].pageX - content.offsetLeft,
                        touches[i].pageY - content.offsetTop);

                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();                   

                drawPath[touches[i].identifier] = touches[i];
            }
        }           
        e.preventDefault();
}

function touchEndHandler(e) {
        var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
        xposition = drawPath[touch.identifier].pageX;
        delete drawPath[touch.identifier];
}`
```

Thanks in advance!